Python - Unpivot Dataframe
I have a table that is indexed on a datetime that has multiple layers (Hub & Delivery Interval) for each datetime:



Datetime
Hub
Delivery Interval
Settlement Point Price




2024-01-01 01:00:00
Houston Hub
1
13.35


2024-01-01 01:00:00
Houston Hub
2
16.60


2024-01-01 01:00:00
Houston Hub
3
17.15


2024-01-01 01:00:00
Houston Hub
4
23.61


2024-01-01 01:00:00
North Hub
1
13.35


2024-01-01 01:00:00
North Hub
2
11.41


2024-01-01 01:00:00
North Hub
3
32.11


2024-01-01 01:00:00
North Hub
4
16.60



Ideally, I'd like to make a new column for all unique entries in the "Hub" column and average all of the "Settlement Point Price" that are the same datetime for the same "Hub". What is the best way to do this? I'm trying to get it to be something like this:



Datetime
Delivery Interval
Houston Hub
North Hub




2024-01-01 01:00:00
N/A (Averaged)
17.68
18.37



Sorry I've spent a long time on this and I'm a beginner. Thank you!
I've tried to dynamically make a new dataframe for each of the unique hubs but someone recommended not to do this and I couldn't get the averaging to work anyway.

Have you read the user guide? Reshaping and pivot tables. Have you read this question? How can I pivot a dataframe?

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for tips like starting with your own research and how to write a good title.

This question is similar to: How can I pivot a dataframe?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I believe this may be as simple as:
df.pivot_table(
index="Datetime",
columns="Hub",
values="Settlement Point Price",
aggfunc="mean")

docs for pandas pivot tables are here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html
